# Need the class of a parent function's returned element

Tags: jquery, function, css-selectors

Somewhat new to jQuery, so excuse the attempt at properly identifying things.

I need an element's id to be reflected in a selector that is a couple functions deep, and I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.

```
$("input[type='file'][id^='pic_']").change(       //I need this element's id...
    function()
    {
        $("."+this.id).hide("fast",
            function()
            {
                //..to be reflected in this class selector
                $("."+this.id).attr("checked", true);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Thanks for your help in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses closures to bring a variable with the id into the scope of the innermost function.

```
$("input[type='file'][id^='pic_']").change(       //I need this element's id...
        function()
        {
                var fileSelector = "." + this.id;
                $(fileSelector).hide("fast",
                        function()
                        {
                                //..to be reflected in this class selector
                                $(fileSelector).attr("checked", true);
                        }
                );
        }
);
```

Comment: My mistake, I should've been more clear:

The element being changed is a file input:
$("input[type='file'][id^='pic_']").change

The element being hidden is a div:
$("."+this.id).hide

And the element being checked is of course a checkbox:
$("."+this.id).attr("checked", true);

What I want to happen is when a user puts a file into the file input, the checkbox and it's label (inside the div) get hidden, and then the checkbox gets checked.

Comment: Oh, well it looks like your original code sample should work fine. Does it not?

Comment: Unfortunately no, since $("."+this.id).attr("checked", true); is being called by a function from $("."+this.id).hide, it returns that element's id and not the element selected by $("input[type='file'][id^='pic_']").change, and they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a question of variable scope:

```
$("#my_input").change(function() {
    var my_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).hide('fast', function() {
        alert(my_id); // Will show an alert with the id from above.
        alert($(this).attr('id')); // *Should* show an alert with the same id.
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).id` is invalid - but the idea is correct - `$(this).attr('id')` or `this.id` would be valid options. But I think a closure is definitely the right idea here.

Comment: using the variable worked great! But I wonder if there is a cleaner way of getting it. Something like this.this.id maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The `this` variable in an event callback is the DOM element hosting the event. In the change function callback, this is the element changed. Therefore:

```
$("input[type='file'][id^='pic_']").change(
  function() {
    $(this).hide("fast",
      function() {
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
      }
    }
  }
}
```